# Execute curl and source the value of curl to environment file in docker

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile, jhipster

Below are the contents of my docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    JHIPSTER_SLEEP=20

# add directly the war
ADD *.war /app.war

VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8081 5701/udp
RUN curl  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/api/startup?lic_key=337075598591269d15xxxxxxxx23fds > /root/tmp_var
RUN export var=$(cat /root/tmp_var)
ENV status="${var}"
CMD if [ "${status}" = "fail" ] ; then exit 1 ; else CMD echo "The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s...${var} .... ${status}" && sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP} && java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war ; fi
```

In the above code curl returns value success or fail. If curl returns fails then my application should not start and if curl returns success then my application should start. In the above code curl is not getting executed and throwing the error while creating the image. The error is **/bin/sh -c curl exited with returned code 127**

Please let me know where I am getting error out

Regards
Satyanvesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image of openjdk:8-jre-alpine does not include the curl command.
You need to install it before running.

```
RUN apk update && apk --no-cache add curl
RUN curl http://xxx.xxx
```

Additional notes.It is the content that I talked about in a comment.
This is an example, and I have not confirmed that it can actually be executed.

Prepare a shell script named `entrypoins.sh` to be an entry point.

```
curl  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx > /root/tmp_var
export var=$(cat /root/tmp_var)
status="${var}"
if [ "${status}" = "fail" ] ; then
  exit 1
else
  echo "The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s...${var} .... ${status}"
  sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}
  java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war
fi
```

Then call it by including it in the Dockerfile.

```
ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
CMD /entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have that IP address running locally on OS, while creating the image its unable to curl the URL running locally on OS

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please ignore the previous comment , after creating the container, while bringing up the container its unable to export the value stored in /root/tmp_var to "var" variable

Comment: I want the CURL command, exporting to variable and checking the if condition 
 executed while bringing up the container

Comment: Dockerfile is intended to create a static image, it is not suitable for dynamically determining something. If you want to create an image that launches jar when you can access a URL, it is good to have a shell that is entrypoint.

Comment: I am new to docker can you please help me out how to add such in ENTRYPOINT

Comment: I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, while bringing up the application i am getting the error as: curl: (6) Could not resolve host: http

Comment: thanks alot, that was typo error, one last thing can we pass -e environment variable to entrypoint.sh

Comment: Thanks alot knanga333, I did that, passing docker run -e environment variable to entrypoint.sh